# How to have same font for the text that is copied from wordpad into textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a text area in my web application. My users can copy text from wordpad
and paste it in textarea.

They want the same text font of the wordpad document to be appear in textarea too. How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retain some formatting by using a rich text editor like tinyMCE ( http://www.tinymce.com/ ). But you're pretty much limited to to sans-serif (arial-like) and serif (times-like) when it comes to fonts. Unless you use webfonts. But even with webfonts you're limited to the fonts you define, and as webfonts often has slightly different names than the desktop fonts (e.g. Meta MT becomes Meta Web) you will not get the correct font when pasting from WordPad

Comment: Actually, tinymce can load the stylesheet from the website it's being used in. This gives it access to exactly the same fonts the website is using. If the fonts are installed locally as well, everything will work together perfectly.

Comment: Thanks elzapp, it is working but the only thing is the editor is appearing for all the textareas in the page, is there anyway we can do it for specific textarea..

Comment: Yes you can limit it to specific textareas. I haven't set up tinyMCE for a while, so I'd have to refer you to the documentation to find out how.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have the font automatically in the text area.  You could give them a WYSIWYG editor that has access to fonts and then you would have to upload all of the wordpad font's to your server (if that's even legal; you'd have to check on the EULA of wordpad), then I believe you would have to create a reference to the font in a dll or on that page.  Here's a link that talks about using fonts.

http://randsco.com/index.php/2009/07/04/p680

In truth it's more headache than you want to deal with.